# jQuery UI tabs OR any other way

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, html, css

I am developing a web-app using HTML5, JavaScript, JQuery, and CSS3.  For this app, I need a tab interface with 5 tabs.  In each tab, I need to do AJAX calls and lots of client-side calculations (graphs, pieCharts, etc).

I am thinking of loading a full page when users click on a particular tab.  jQueryUI tabs will make the page huge, slow, and difficult to handle.

I come to know about Ajax feature jQueryUI tabs, but it is not supporting webpage with lots of component (only text is allowed).

What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps you could post what you have? Maybe a photoshopped layout? Napkin scribbles? Anything? Also, why would jQueryUI tabs make it too slow?

Comment: Why would using JqueryUI tabs make it huge, slow and difficult to handle? I have used JqueryUI tabs and ajax loaded all manner of content into them.

Comment: it is quite huge and i have to fetch lot of data from xml using AJAX...
now so i am in favor of 5 tabs = 5 Pages . load each page for each tab, is there any way for it ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could consider that will allow you to use the jQuery UI tabs and avoid loading all tabs on the same page would be for each tab to contain an `iframe`.  The `iframe` document for the current tab would then be the only content that would load, and you can build each tab page as its own web page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery BBQ.  It leverages the hashchange and allows for content to be loaded and cached via AJAX.

It also plays nice with the jQuery UI tabs.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/